# Creating point clusters of a specified size using R

Tags: r, clustering

Given a set of points `(x,y)`, I would like to create K clusters of these points similar to the k-means algorithm. The difference is that I would like to define the number of points contained in a cluster, in my situation I would like them to all be equal. For example, take 30 points and put them into 3 sets of 10 points so that the total distance between points in all clusters is minimized. Ideally I would like to implement the solution using R. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think this would have a unique solution in some circumstances. It seems very close to asking for quantiles in more than one dimension. Are you sure you really want to constrain the clustering in such a way? (Imagine if you had 11 of the points in the exact same location) In a brief search I was able to turn up this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320399000576), but I could not tell if any R implementation existed. Try checking out the [Cran Task view for clustering](http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/web/views/Cluster.html).

Answer (score 1):

Give the [spatstat](http://www.spatstat.org/) package a go - the package was designed by CSIRO for spatial point pattern analysis. There's a very extensive paper going over the use of the package on the [CSIRO website](http://www.csiro.au/resources/Spatial-Point-Patterns-in-R.html).

Answer (score 1):

How different are your cluster sizes with plain k-means ?
Take a look at
[k-means-algorithm-variation-with-equal-cluster-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452576/k-means-algorithm-variation-with-equal-cluster-size) (Python, not R).